# JavaScript if statement with some Boolean only works first time

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

I have these two functions, the first one (move_c(i)) runs when the user clicks on a (source) image, and the second one (move_to_c1(i)) runs when the user clicks on a (destination) div.

And there is a Boolean value (cp) which flip flops between true and false each time the second function is run.

The images are red or yellow, and the idea is that red will only move when cp == true and yellow will only move when cp == false, but it only works the very first time, after that it fails to do its job and I don't understand why.

Red must go first. The first move, the if condition works, red && true. Yellow && true does not move for the first move (which is correct). But for subsequent moves the if condition isn't working.

[You can see it in action here.](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/harleycalvert/scgame/blob/scgame/index.html)

[And the code is here.](https://github.com/harleycalvert/scgame)

Oh... and I've only implemented this on the circle game not the square.

```
var cp = true;
function move_c(i) {
  alert(document.getElementById(i).className + " " + cp);
  this.image_c = i;
  if (((document.getElementById(i).className == 'red') && (cp == true)) || ((document.getElementById(i).className == 'yellow') && (cp == false))) {
    c1.setAttribute('onclick', 'move_to_c1(image_c)');
    c2.setAttribute('onclick', 'move_to_c2(image_c)');
    c3.setAttribute('onclick', 'move_to_c3(image_c)');
    c4.setAttribute('onclick', 'move_to_c4(image_c)');
    c5.setAttribute('onclick', 'move_to_c5(image_c)');
    c6.setAttribute('onclick', 'move_to_c6(image_c)');
    c7.setAttribute('onclick', 'move_to_c7(image_c)');
    c8.setAttribute('onclick', 'move_to_c8(image_c)');
    c9.setAttribute('onclick', 'move_to_c9(image_c)');
  }
}

function move_to_c1(i) {
  if (document.getElementById(i).name == 'c' || document.getElementById(i).name == 'c2' || document.getElementById(i).name == 'c4' || document.getElementById(i).name == 'c5') {
    document.getElementById("c1").appendChild(document.getElementById(i));
    document.getElementById(i).style.zIndex = 1;
    document.getElementById(i).setAttribute('name', 'c1');
    cp = !cp;
  }
}
```

Comment: is `cp` always a boolean? then you need not to check against a boolean value.

Comment: I love the idea of a rebellious boolean. "No, I don't want to be true!"

Comment: Also, why are you setting the `onclick` attribute, when you can add event listeners?

Comment: cp is always a boolean, git hub just updated so you can check it out now, not sure about event listeners, don't know about them

Comment: **after that it fails to do its job** can you explain ? I tried your app and it seemed to work.

Comment: red must go first then yellow should go second, but red can go second

Answer (score 2):

I recommend opening your page in Chrome, and using the developer tools. You can open the console by pressing F12 on your keyboard.

The console will show you that exceptions are being thrown from the `c3.setAttribute` lines in `move_c` after the first smiley has been moved. This appears to be because name `c3` is changed to refer to multiple elements when the smiley is moved. When it refers to multiple elements rather than the expected single element, then the `setAttribute` is not available on the group.

<strike>The fix is to avoid calling `c3.setAttribute('onclick', 'move_to_c3(image_c)');` and similar for smileys which have been moved/renamed. The most straight forward way to do that is to check before each `setAttribute`:</strike>

```
if (c1) {
    c1.setAttribute(.....);
}
```

You can change the code to avoid giving multiple objects the same name. Instead of setting the name attribute, you can save the game state in a separate object. Add `var gamestate = [];` somewhere at the top, and then replace `document.getElementById(i).setAttribute('name', 'c1');` with `gamestate[i] = 'c1';`. Then you will be able to lookup the position of an image by accessing `gamestate[i]`. You can log the complete game state any time you want using `console.log(gamestate);`.

Note that once you have the console open, you can use `console.log` instead of `alert` to see what's going on. It is much more comfortable than confirming alert dialogs all the time. Also it allows you to inspect the inside of objects in more detail as you'll see if you try `console.log(gamestate);`.

Once you've got that working, then start studying arrays and for loops. It will help to simplify your code by removing all the repetitions.

Comment: And, additionally: once the c[1-9] / "onclick" attribute is set the first time, it's not unset after that. That's why his logic only works the first time. Actually the conditional `if (cp && red || !cp && yellow)` should rather take place in "move_to_cX"

Comment: @Joel Yes, there may be more issues. I only looked at the most immediate problem and my intention was more about introducing the developer tools. Teach a man to fish :)